# Adding An Arbitrary Column Into the Result of the SELECT Statement

Tags: sql

I want to select city_id and customer_address from customer table but I also want to add an extra column which inludes only "customer" word to indicate the result derived from customer table.

Desired Output:

```
Table       ID  Address
customer    12  Address 1
customer    32  Address 2
customer    212 Address 3
customer    2   Address 4
customer    32  Address 5
customer    212 Address 6
customer    21  Address 7
customer    21  Address 8
```

Statement something below would be great:

```
SELECT ADDCOLUMN("customer"), city_id, customer_address FROM customer;
```

customer table schema is below:

[image]

Comment: SELECT 'customer' AS OMG , city_id, customer_address FROM customer;`

Answer (score 1):

In T-SQL `SELECT [table] = 'customer', city_id, customer_address FROM customer;` works, as does `SELECT 'customer' AS [table], city_id, customer_address FROM customer;`.